# Are there databases of case-level lawsuit settlement amounts?

Tags: settlement

I am looking for case-level settlement information (amounts, time it took, etc) for an academic research project. I'm not picky on the specific area of law -- any area would be fine, provided that I can observe the actual settlement amounts, the initial claimed damages, and the timelines.

Comment: Virtually every settlement I've heard of keeps the amount confidential, except for at least one case where one side really wanted to make the point that the settlement was for $0.

Comment: @RyanM What about cases involving governments -- would they have to disclose settlement amounts?

Comment: Ah, good point.  Those are usually public, I think.  I was thinking of private litigants.

Comment: @RyanM Do you know any source that collects such cases and data? (private, paid sources are good too)

Comment: Here's a collection of a bunch, from a quick search: https://www.justice.gov/crt/settlements-and-lawsuits

Comment: @RyanM. Thanks. I have some specific questions but I'm realizing it might not be most efficient to keep chatting here in public. If you are willing to chat a little bit and help me privately, let me know.

Comment: It looks like there's a [bill to be considered by the US Senate](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/117/hr27) that would _create_ such a database, but that doesn't really solve your current problem.  It does suggest that a broad database (at least for federal government settlements) doesn't currently exist, though.  I don't have much specific information that would be helpful: I'm mostly just searching.  I don't know that I'd be much help.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Westlaw](https://legal.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/westlaw/jury-verdicts) and [LexisNexis](https://www.lexisnexis.com/en-us/products/verdict-and-settlement-analyzer.page) have large databases of verdicts and settlements, with national coverage.

Answer (score 1):

There are disclosure databases for medical malpractice settlements, and class action lawsuit settlements. Government lawsuit (against or by the government) settlement usually have to be a matter of public record.

Complete and representative databases of other private party lawsuit settlements are hard to obtain because most settlements make the terms of the settlement and its amount confidential.